# An exercise on spectra of bounded operators

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, functional-analysis

> Let $X$ be an infinite dimensional complex Banach space, $T$ a bounded operator on $X$ with $T^n$ compact for some $n\geq 1$. Prove that the spectrum of $T$ is of the form $\sigma(T)=\{0,\lambda_1,...,\lambda_N\}$ for $N \in \mathbb{N}\cup \{\infty\}$, and $\lambda_i \rightarrow 0$ if the sequence is infinite. $\lambda_i$ are eigenvalues of $T$.

... from Bollobas' "Linear Analysis".
I'm stuck on a couple of points, nonetheless here is my try.

- $0$ must be in the spectrum, otherwise $T^n$ would be an invertible compact operator on the infinite dimensional space $X$
- suppose $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $T$. Therefore, $\lambda I -T$ is non injective, and so must be $\lambda^nI-T^n=S(\lambda I - T)$ for some $S$. Hence, since the ground field is $\mathbb{C}$ and here $n-$th roots always exist, we know that the point spectrum must be $\sigma_p(T)\subseteq \{ n-$th roots of eigenvalues of $T^n\}$. Since $T^n$ is compact, the eigenvalues of $T^n$ are at most countably many and arrangable in such a way they go to $0$, if there are infinitely many. Hence this also holds for the eigenvalues of $T$.
- now I must prove there is nothing more in $\sigma(T)$ other than $0$ and $\sigma_p(T)$. If $\lambda$ is not zero and not an $n-$th root of an eigenvalue of $T^n$, then, $\lambda \in \sigma(T)$ would imply by $\lambda^nI-T^n=S(\lambda I - T)=(\lambda I - T)S$ that $\lambda^n \in \sigma(T^n)$, absurd.

How about the case when $\lambda$ is not zero **and** an $n-$th root of an eigenvalue of $T^n$? Also, is it always true that $T$ will have an eigenvalue?

---

Edit: the answer to the second question is contained in the next exercise in the book and it is no, there is a compact operator on $l^p$ without eigenvalues.

Edit (2): the $\lambda_i$ should be eigenvalues of $T$

Comment: Spectral Mapping Theorem implies that if $ 0 \neq \lambda \in \sigma (T)$ then  $ \lambda^{n} \in \sigma (T^{n})$ and hence $ \lambda^{n}$ is an eigen value of $T^{n}$.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Wouldn't we need $T$ to be self-adjoint for the Spectral Mapping Theorem?

Comment: Can you explain why this proves that residual and continuous spectra of $T$ (minus $0$) are empty?

Comment: @SeverinSchraven We only need compactness of $T$ to conclude $\sigma(T)=\{0\} \cup$ eigenvalues

Comment: @SeverinSchraven Only for arbitrary continuous functions. For polynomials this is a purely algebraic fact.

Comment: @warm-fish My comment was in response to KaviRamaMurthy's comment. I am not sure the theorem he mentions is true in this generality (maybe I misunderstood your response).

Comment: @SeverinSchraven Okay, I supposed he was talking about this spectral theorem: $T$ compact on a Banach space $\implies \sigma(T)=\{0\} \cup$ eigenvalues

Comment: @MaoWao Of course, I am stupid...

Comment: For every bounded operator $T$ on a Banach space, and every analytic function $f$ defined on a neighborhood of  $\sigma(T)$ one has that $f(\sigma(T))=\sigma(f(T))$.

Comment: Could you please provide a reference for this? @Ruy

Comment: Every isolated point in the spectrum of a bounded operator is an eigenvalue.

Comment: @warm_fish, a reference is Rudin, Functional Analysis, Theorem III.10.28.

Comment: Great, thanks! @Ruy